# Detecting cell is selected in UITableView in cellForRowAtIndexPath in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am trying to detect whether a `UITableViewCell` is selected or not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This is what I have done so far with objective C:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath];
if(cell.isSelected) {
    NSlog(@"This cell is selected")
}
```

I'm not able to access the property `isSelected` of the `UITableviewCell` in Swift. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if cell.selected {` is the right way to go.

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(someIndexPath) {
  if cell.selected {
    print("This cell is selected")
  }
}
```

**[Update: Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623263-isselected)**

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: someIndexPath) {
  if cell.isSelected {
    print("This cell is selected")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    print("cell selected at row \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way, Get the indexPath

```
var someIndexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
```

Deselect when it is actually selected with isSelected property of cell.

```
var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(someIndexPath)
if cell.isSelected {
   tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(someIndexPath, animated: true)
}
```